# Как в ангуляре корректно выстроить небольшую архитектуру модели?

Tags: архитектура, angular, модель-данных

У каждой страницы есть несколько get запросов. 
К примеру, есть у меня 4 get запроса на получение данных (first, second, third, fourh),  я знаю, что first и second относится к странице под роутом "firstPage", а third, fourth - к странице под роутом "secondPage".
Я не хочу сразу делать все get запросы (то есть, я хочу, если перешел по роуту secondPage, то и получать его данные).

```
{
 firstPage: {
  one: [],
  two: []
 },
 secondPage: {
  three: [],
  four: []
 }
}
```

Где или как бы разместить этот единый общий объект всех страниц, чтобы я мог в любом компоненте узнать какие массивы лежат в той или иной странице (то есть,  обращаясь к полю объекта secondPage моя ide мне могла бы подсказать, что в ней два массива)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте просто синглтон, который будет шарить данные по всему приложению:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface Data {
    firstPage: {
        one: any[];
        two: any[];
    };
    secondPage: {
        three: any[];
        four: any[];
    }
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DataService {
    private data$ = new BehaviorSubject<Data>({
        firstPage: {
            one: [],
            two: []
        },
        secondPage: {
            three: [],
            four: []
        }
    });

    public getDataStream(): Observable<Data> {
        return this.data$.asObservable();
    }

    public getData(): Data {
        return this.data$.getValue();
    }

    public getDataByPage(page: string) {
        return this.getData()[page];
    }

    public setData(page: string, data: object): void {
        const currentData = this.getData();

        this.data$.next({
            ...currentData,
            [page]: data
        });
    }
}
```

Используем `BehaviorSubject` для кеширования. Далее, если вы говорите, что знаете какие данные относятся к каким компонентам то просто делайте запросы и сеттите новое значение:

```
// first.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-first',
    templateUrl: './first.component.html'
})
export class FirstComponent {
    constructor(private api: ApiService, private dataService: DataService) {
        this.api.getDataForFirstPage().pipe(
            tap((data) => {
                this.dataService.setData('firstPage', data);
                // предполагаем, что `data` это объект со свойствами `one, two`
            })
        ).subscribe(....);
    }
}
```

P.S. - можете также добавить проверку на то, что данные уже загрузились, чтобы не делать повторно запрос при N-ом инициализации компонента.

Comment: Спасибо! Была идея с синглтоном, но не знал, как бы его корректно реализовать. Буду разбираться!

Comment: Вы не подскажите, в чем принцип использования tap? Какую роль он несет? При каких условиях его использовать?

Comment: @bruce, https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html